# express wrong req.url when coming from proxy?

Tags: node.js, url, express, proxy

Express is showing wrong req.url when the request is coming from a client that has proxy turned on.

Example:

The client has a proxy setting: server.com:4000 and makes a request example.com/request

express server.com:4000 than shows req.url: http://www.example.comhttp://www.example.comhttp://www.example.com/request

But if you do a request directly against server without any proxy setting:
server.com:4000/request
req.url shows correct: /request

why is this?
How can i solve this so i always get req.url=/request even if the client has proxy setting?